# GridMvc render column based on if condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview

I am trying to render a column based on condition in gridmvc like below  :

```
@model IEnumerable< BasicSuprema.Models.BioUserModel >
@using GridMvc.Html

@helper CustomRenderingOfColumn(BasicSuprema.Models.BioUserModel users)
{
    if (users.cardType == 0)
    {
        <span class="label label-success">Normal</span>
    }
    else if(users.cardType == 1)
    {
        <span class="label label-important">ByPass</span>
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
  @Html.Grid(Model).Named("UsersGrid").Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Add(c => c.ID).Titled("ID");
                        columns.Add(c => c.cardType).Titled("Card Type")
                        .RenderValueAs(c => c.CustomRenderingOfColumn(c));

                    }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```

I get a compilation error

```
'BasicSuprema.Models.BioUserModel' does not contain a definition for 'CustomRenderingOfColumn' and no extension method 'CustomRenderingOfColumn' accepting a first argument of type 'BasicSuprema.Models.BioUserModel' could be found
```

This error is on the line `.RenderValueAs(c => c.CustomRenderingOfColumn(c));`
I have tried the solution from [SO](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/discussions/542948%20%22%22)

[1](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/discussions/542948%20%22%22): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24415952/2083526 "GridMvc and if statement when adding columns" as well as this one [gridmvc.codeplex.com](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/discussions/542948%20%22%22)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be a late answer but I have recently used `RenderValueAs` based on if condition. In your case, the error is pretty clear that tells there is no method definition for `BasicSuprema.Models.BioUserModel` as `CustomRenderingOfColumn`.

So, you should change it;

```
.RenderValueAs(c => c.CustomRenderingOfColumn(c));
```

to

```
.RenderValueAs(c => CustomRenderingOfColumn(c));
```

Because `CustomRenderingOfColumn` is not part of your model. (`BioUserModel`)

Complete code looks like;

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Named("UsersGrid").Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add(c => c.ID).Titled("ID");
            columns.Add(c => c.cardType).Titled("Card Type")
            .RenderValueAs(c => CustomRenderingOfColumn(c));

        }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```